# ruby time interval not working 45 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby `2.4`

```
start_time = '9:00 am'.to_time 

# => 2020-11-03 09:00:00 +1100
```

divide by 15 minutes interval  and multiply the interval

```
interval = 15.minutes 

x = start_time.to_i / interval

y = x * interval
Time.at(y).strftime('%I:%M %P')
# => 9:00 am
```

This works fine for the interval 15, 30, 60 minutes but gives `8:45 am` for 45.minutes interval

Comment: Note: Ruby 2.4 is a little old these days, 2.7 is current. It's worth upgrading if you can, and there shouldn't be any major issues with that.

Comment: `x = start_time.to_i / interval` is an odd thing to see. What's the end goal here?

Comment: When running this code in 2.7 I get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'strftime' for 1604325600:Integer)`

Comment: @tadman updated my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are aware of this, but like you can see in your first code block

> ```
> start_time = '9:00 am'.to_time
> # => 2020-11-03 09:00:00 +1100
> ```

`start_time` is not only the time 9:00 am, but fills in the blancs by taking today's date and your current zone offset. When you then call `to_i` this time (including date and offset) is converted to an **integer** timestamp of seconds since Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC).

```
start_time = Time.new(2020,11,3,9,0,0,'+11:00')
timestamp = start_time.to_i
#=> 1604354400
```

Before we move on it's important to note that in Ruby **dividing two integers will truncate the remainder**.

```
13 / 5.0 #=> 2.6
13 / 5r  #=> (13/5)
13 / 5   #=> 2
```

You can compare

> ```
> x = start_time.to_i / interval
> y = x * interval
> ```

with

```
a = 13
b = 5

c = a / b
c * b #=> 10
```

The timestamp `1604354400` is not completely dividable by `2700` (`45.minutes`) and thus truncates the remainder. I will be using [`divmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Integer.html#method-i-divmod) to both divide and get the remainder.

```
timestamp.divmod(2700) #=> [594205, 900]
```

Meaning that `2700` fits `594205` times within `1604354400`, but leaves a remainder of `900` (15 minutes) which is truncated. For this reason your final result is missing 15 minutes.

If you want to arrive at you original value again you'll have to add this remainder.

```
interval = 2700 # 45 minutes
count, remainder = timestamp.divmod(interval)

resulting_timestamp = count * interval + remainder
resulting_time = Time.at(resulting_timestamp)
```

Now `resulting_time` should be `2020-11-03 09:00:00 +1100`, however I'm not in the same time zone so I get a different result.

I'm not exactly sure why you are using `Time` for this. It seems like you want to do `9.hours / 45.minutes` which does fit.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to divide the day into time slots, e.g. 45 minute intervals:

```
  0:00   0:45   1:30   2:15   3:00   3:45   4:30   5:15
  6:00   6:45   7:30   8:15   9:00   9:45  10:30  11:15
 12:00  12:45  13:30  14:15  15:00  15:45  16:30  17:15
 18:00  18:45  19:30  20:15  21:00  21:45  22:30  23:15
```

and that you want to find the one, your `start_time` falls into.

Dividing the time by 45 (minutes) and multiplying it by 45 (minutes) afterwards is the correct approach (using integer division). But in order to do so, you have to use the time's [`hour`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#hour-method) and [`min`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#min-method)ute values:

```
require 'active_support/time'
ENV['TZ'] = 'Australia/Sydney'

start_time = '9:00 am'.to_time 
#=> 2020-11-03 09:00:00 +1100

minutes = start_time.hour * 60 + start_time.min
#=> 540

minutes = (minutes / 45) * 45
#=> 540

hour, min = minutes.divmod(60)
#=> [9, 0]

start_time.change(hour: hour, min: min)
#=> 2020-11-03 09:00:00 +1100
```

[`Time#change`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-change) automatically sets seconds and sub-seconds to zero.

Note that the above codes works in *minutes* and therefore uses the integer value `45`. If you want to use Rails' `45.minutes` instead (which has an integer value of 2700), you have to convert everything to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This might be some quirk of older Ruby time libraries, but this works:

```
interval = 45.minutes
y = Time.at((start_time.to_i / interval) * interval)
y.strftime('%I:%M %P')
# => "09:00 am"
```

Comment: "08:45 am" still

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Ruby 2.7.1.

Comment: @tadman Are you using `start_time = Time.new(2020,11,3,9,0,0,'+11:00')`?

Comment: I used the `start_time = '9:00 am'.to_time` in the original question.

Comment: used start_time = '9:00 am'.to_time